# Ошибка назначения точки стрельбы в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытаюсь сделать игру типа примитивного 2д шутера, как начал делать стрельбу так сразу все на перекосяк пошло, юнити думает, что я не указал позицию начала стрельбы, хотя она указана.

возможно как то пофиксить?

код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;

    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform shotPoint;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput * speed;

        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x));
        

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);

    }
}
```

Ошибка: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable shotPoint of PlayerControler has not been assigned.

Comment: Ты в инспекторе unity в поле shotPoint что-то клал?

Comment: конечно, подлючил пулю, и сам shotPoint

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, это ооочень медленно! Запомни, что нельзя в FixedUpdate делать Instantiate из-за того, что это довольно тяжёлый вызов и ты его даже не каждый кадр пытаешься вызвать, а каждый такт!
Во-вторых, если ты хочешь, чтобы твоя пуля летела, на ней должен быть компонент rigidbody2D и коллайдер для столкновений.
В-третьих, пуля должна быть префабом и прокинута в инспектор, там же нужно установить начальную скорость, а в скипте уже непосредственно изменять импульс этой самой Пули созданной. Ты сейчас изменяешь Rigidbody2D своего персонажа, а не пули.

Если есть острая необходимость спаунить пули, то ты можешь выставить временной интервал, например, 1 раз в 60 кадров.

Вот переписанный пример, который я проверил на своей машине:

```
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
[SerializeField] private Vector2 moveVelocity;

[SerializeField] private GameObject bullet;
[SerializeField] private Transform shotPoint;

[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb = null;

// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

private void Update()
{
    Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveVelocity = moveInput * speed;

    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x));

    if (Time.frameCount % 60 == 0)
    {
        CreateBullet();
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}

private void CreateBullet()
{
    var bulletRigidbody2D = Instantiate(this.bullet, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation).GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    bulletRigidbody2D.AddForce(bulletRigidbody2D.transform.up * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ошибка: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable shotPoint of PlayerControler has not been assigned.

UnassignedReferenceException происходит когда объект не назначен полю компонента. Убедитесь что ссылка есть, перейдите в иерархии в сцене или в префабе на объект с PlayerController и назначьте пулю. Убедитесь также что ссылка имеет связь на объект пули из самой сцены(и пулю потом никто не уничтожает) или на префаб пули. Если же PlayerController находится в префабе то ссылка на пулю должна вести только на другой префаб или на объект внутри этого же префаба где и PlayerController.

Также убедитесь что вы не ставили ссылку на пулю в самом скрипте, выбрав файл скрипта и просмотрев инспектор - должно быть пусто во всех параметрах (это значения по умолчанию, вот такой инспектор https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoBehaviour.html#default-object-references)